# Needed Example of while loop in Nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

Could someone please explain me how to write a While loop in NASAM assembly language , example which registers are involved what mov operations are needed and how the counter is kept, i'm trying to grasp assembly but it's a little tricky at the begining...

Thanks Guys

Btw : I'm trying to learn this language for a course i'm taking

Comment: NASM is not a language, it's a program, an assembler.

Comment: Right. Nasm is an assembler... and it has its own Forum - http://forum.nasm.us If I answer the question here, they'll just close it. :)

Answer (score 6):

I guess you ask about x86 assembler?
In assembler there is no while loop (maybe you can use special macros for that sometime, depends on the Assembler). You have to construct by your own. You can use assembler commands like

```
jne, jnz, je, jz, cmp, inc, dec
```

or some more special outdated command

```
jcxz, loop
```

for example:

```
mov ecx,255

L1:

dec ecx
jne L1
ret
```

This example counts the value in the register ecx until 0 and then left the loop.
Another example but which count above.

```
mov ecx,0

L2:

inc ecx
cmp ecx, 255
jne L2
ret
```

Comment: Alright Suppose if i wanted to make a hypothetical while loop that takes a # suppose 16 and divides it by two until the quotient is 0 
i would need to perform a compare each time the number is divided by 2 , Also i assume " loop: " is a label and not a function correct ?

Comment: In this case you should simply initialize a register (maybe eax) with that number you want to divide by 2. In this special case you can use shift by one bit to the right (= equivalent to integer division by 2) and leave the loop if the number in eax is already 0. And yes you are right loop is a label.

Comment: don't use `loop:` as a label: It's also [an instruction mnemonic](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LOOP:LOOPcc.html), so you'll get weird syntax errors from some assemblers.

Comment: Yes, not a good idea to use 'loop' as a Label. I fixed the answer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

A loop needs a starting point (probably with a label for convenience), some stuff in the middle (the loop body), and an instruction to jump back to the start. The jump may be conditional to terminate the loop based on certain conditions, or there may be something in the loop body that explicitly terminates the loop by jumping somewhere else. There are no particular restrictions on what registers or memory locations or instructions you use, although, with some instruction sets (like x86 and x86-64) that have specific instructions that are designed to make writing loops easier, and may have some hardcoded dependencies on certain registers. However, again, there's also no requirement to actually use those.

Aside from that, your question is vague enough there isn't really much more to add, other than that the programmers reference manuals from the manufacturer of the CPU you're writing for (Intel, AMD, ......) are highly recommended references, and usually free to download.

Answer (score 0):

Many macro assemblers do indeed support a WHILE macro:

http://www.oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_8/CH08-9.html#HEADING9-90

Here's some 6809 code written by Motorola in the 70s:

```
  WHILE  B,GT,(0,Y) 
    ORA  B,X 
    DECB 
  ENDWH
```

(For clarity, the only "actual" 6809 opcodes used there are ORA and DECB.)

Comment: NASM doesn't support this kind of thing.  MASM does have some high-level directives like `IF`, and probably loops, but this is a NASM question.